# Delphi to C# (TStringStream + Base64) different result

Tags: c#, delphi, base64, converters

Good day. May be some body know a true way to get same result in Delphi and C# for next lines.

```
var
  aStrStream: TStringStream;
  aStr: string;
begin
  aStr := 'Test';
  aStrStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  aStrStream.Write(aStr, SizeOf(Length(aStr)));
  aStrStream.Position := 0;
  aStr := DIMime.MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF(aStrStream.DataString);
  aStrStream.Free;

  //Got yJFVAA==

end;
```

AND

```
Encoding dest = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding src = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] srcBytes = src.GetBytes("Test");
byte[] destBytes = Encoding.Convert(src, dest, srcBytes);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(destBytes));

//Got VGVzdA==
```

Update 1:

Thank all for yours detailed answer. But situation is next. I have a src code of some program which generate a based64 string for soksifikator. And i try convert it to C#. This program have a lot of lines like this:

```
aLen := Length(aObj.RuleProxyName); //aObj.RuleProxyName - string
aStrStream.Write(aLen, SizeOf(aLen));
if aLen > 0 then
  aStrStream.Write(aObj.RuleProxyName[1], aLen);
```

And this is a reason why i cannot use `aStrStream.WriteString`.

Comment: `aStrStream.Write(aStr, SizeOf(Length(aStr)));` should be `aStrStream.Write(aStr, SizeOf(Char)*Length(aStr));` or `aStrStream.WriteString(aStr);`.

Comment: Thanks. `aStrStream.WriteString(aStr);` works.  But `aStrStream.Write(aStr, SizeOf(Char)*Length(aStr));` give old result `yJFVAA==` . I'm trying rewrite some part of old program and it use `Write` function.

Comment: I think that should have been `Write(PChar(aStr)^,..)`, sorry.

Comment: foolsoft, what delphi version are we talking about?

Comment: @whosrdaddy. I'm really don't know =) Because i don't know Delphi language. Think it is 7.

Comment: So basically, the delphi code is encoding the length of the string and the string itself. You need the answer in C#, right?

Comment: Yes. I need port this code to C#.

Comment: @foolsoft I've updated my answer but really you need to do some more thinking and investigation. Your next task is to understand what the Delphi code really does.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The reason that I assumed that the C# code was the target is that the Delphi code is clearly wrong. But as I discussed, the C# code is odd too. Now, it would seem that both code excerpts in the original question are bogus. There's really no point trying to get the C# to match the Delphi code that you posted because the Delphi code is all wrong.

What you really need to do is work out what the real Delphi code (as opposed to your mock up code) is doing.

Let's look at this:

```
aLen := Length(aObj.RuleProxyName); //aObj.RuleProxyName - string
aStrStream.Write(aLen, SizeOf(aLen));
if aLen > 0 then
  aStrStream.Write(aObj.RuleProxyName[1], aLen);
```

That writes a 4 byte little endian integer string length to a stream, and then follows it with the ANSI encoded text. The Delphi code is using a `TStringStream` but that is an abuse of that class. That class is used to store text, but clearly it contains a mix of binary and ANSI encoded text. This code should really be using a memory stream or similar.

In C# the excerpt above would translate as:

```
string str = "Test";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(str.Length);
writer.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
```

The next question though is what `DIMime.MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF` does. We cannot know that since it's not a standard class. As I said in my original answer, you should be wary of any code that attempts to base64 encode text rather than binary input.

So, in order to make headway you'll want to try to understand what `DIMime.MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF` actually does. Given that this seems to be a pre-Unicode Delphi, it almost certainly treats the input string as a byte array and encodes that in which case you can finish of the excerpt above with `Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())`.

---

**Original answer**

The Delphi code is a bit of a mess. For instance, `SizeOf(Length(aStr))` makes no sense. But in any case you shouldn't be using `Write` and instead should use `WriteString`.

But even then, you are getting quite mixed up between text and binary. You go to all that trouble to convert the text to ASCII, and then do `aStrStream.DataString` which simply converts it back to UTF-16. Which you then feed to `MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF`. You may as well just write: `MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF('Test')`, which would fail in the same way, I think.

I'd start again and write the code exactly as it was done in the C# version. I would avoid `TStringStream` and take advantage of the fact that Delphi's `TEncoding` class is designed to be as close as possible in usage as the .net `Encoding` class. So you really can make a literal translation of this code.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.NetEncoding;

procedure Main;
var
  dest, src: TEncoding;
  srcBytes, destBytes: TBytes;
begin
  dest := TEncoding.ASCII;
  src := TEncoding.Unicode;
  srcBytes := src.GetBytes('Test');
  destBytes := TEncoding.Convert(src, dest, srcBytes);
  Writeln(TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(destBytes));
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
VGVzdA==
```

If you don't have the `NetEncoding` unit available (it was added in XE7), you can use any other byte array to base64 encoder that you have at hand.

I have to say that I am quite sceptical of your use of `DIMime.MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF` because it converts text to base64. Which will require an implicit encoding of the text to a binary representation. And that implicit encoding is crucially important and should not be hidden away in that manner. This is what I mean by saying that you are getting mixed up between text and binary. Remember that base64 encodes binary as text. And decodes text to binary. But `MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF` converts text to text which implies an implicit text encoding.

My own personal rule is that you should never do such a conversion using an implicit text encoding. If you start with text first convert to binary using an explicitly chosen encoding. Then encode that binary with base64.

Finally, I do wonder why the code converts from text to ASCII and then to UTF-16. That seems a rather strange decision. Is the C# code really doing what you need it to do?

Comment: Thank for answer. I added update to main post with few details.  I use this conversion in C# because as i read before `TStringStream` use ASCII for `DataString` property.